# How do I access my Google Drive (G: ) Windows Mount from the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Tags: google-drive-api, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount

I'm working on a project that I have stored on my Google Drive mount on Windows, and I would like to use Linux for portions of that project. The Windows Subsystem for Linux has served me well for most of my projects, but I've never had the need to mount a network drive. While it's not imperative that I use my Google Drive mount for this project (I could easily place it in my `/downloads` or `/documents` folder), I was curious as to how I could access my Google Drive from WSL.

I attempted to create a new mount via:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/googledrive`

This successfully created the directory, and then I used the command:

`sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/googledrive`

This too seemed to be successful.

I was able `cd` to the `/mnt/googledrive` directory, but I couldn't access any of my files (it reported the '.' location was unavailable).

Perhaps I've simply misunderstood what I was doing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround, not using the "Google Drive" application but the "Backup and Sync" for individuals (https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

Basicaly it's doing the same for me but in a different way. Backup and Sync will permit you to backup your drive to Google but also Sync your Google Drive localy.

By choosing to sync your drive localy, you can even select some folders, the files are sync to the "C" drive under your user profile at the same level of your "My Documents" folder.

Using that way, you can access your files from your linux with the working /mnt/c/... link.

If that answer is too late for you, might be still in time for others ;-)